# iOS: "Include of non-modular header" with libxml

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, header, libxml2

I'm trying to build my own framework 'VBL' that uses [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML) which is based on libxml.dylib

The framework is building fine, but whenever I'm trying to use it in any project, I got the following error:

```
"Include of non-modular header inside framework module VBL.CXMLNode"
```

And that's specifically because in header CXMLNode.h inside my framework, I have to include libxml as follows:

```
#include <libxml/tree.h>
```

Is it safe to set the following property inside Build Settings to YES?

```
allow non-modular included in framework modules
```

But this will not work with Swift anyways, so any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you solve your question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to hide the `#include <libxml/tree.h>` in a private header or in the .m file if you can.

You can also try to create a `module.modulemap` file with the libxml root header inside to fool the swift compiler:

```
module Libxml [system] {
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h"
    export *
}
```

Then place the file inside a folder, -module/module.modulemap- for example.

Once you did that you should link it in `import paths` within the `swift compiler search path` section of the target `build setting`, and to the target's `header search path` :

```
$(SRCROOT)/module
```

Then in your code, you can use `@import libxml;`

Comment: thanks Loegic, it works but how can update inside podspec ?

Comment: @ios_user, I'm sorry but I don't understand the question ? You want to update a dependency ?

Comment: i mean i edit the pod modulemapp file to add the missing no modular header inside the list of pods, but if i wish to work without to edit manually in the pods, rather inside my podspec file, when i make pod lint,  it don't work

Comment: Ok yes you can, there is not a lot of documentation for it but try to search for 'pod spec module map file'